# A tricky way to using <%# Bind %> in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, listview, bind

In ASP.NET, I can use <%# Bind %> to achieve two-way data binding, then the data source control can complete update function for me.

However, I think it's only easy when you just show simple format, like

```
<%# Bind("InsertDate") %>
```

But, if I want to show 'N/A' when InsertDate is not exist. then how to use <%# Bind %> to achieve the condition check?

I know Bind function supports format string, like

```
<%# Bind("InsertDate", "0:{dd MMM yyyy}") %>
```

But it cannot change format base on InsertDate's content.

I even try to use:

```
<%# FormatString(Bind("InsertDate").ToString()) %>
```

It seems's not working which normally works for Eval function.

Another example is I have a bitwise column in table (like 5) which is represented by a checkboxlist wrapped by ListView control, like

```
    <asp:checkboxlist>
     <asp:ListItem value="1" text="OptionA">
     <asp:ListItem value="2" text="OptionB">
     <asp:ListItem value="4" text="OptionC">
    </asp:checkboxlist>
```

then how to use <%# Bind %> to achieve two-way bind to bind the bitwise column to this checkboxlist?

Currently what I do is:

1. set checkboxlist's selected item(value) in ListView's ItemDataBound event handler
2. using a HiddenField and bind the data to this hiddenfield to
   achieve two-way data bind.
3. In LivtView's ItemUpdating event handler, I update above ListViewUpdateEventArgs' NewValue property to the value I want. and then the EntityDataSource can do the update operation correctly.

But I think this method is not easy and good.

So is there any other better method to do this?

Comment: `FormatString(Bind("InsertDate").ToStrig()` - you have a typo there, shouldn't it be `.ToString()`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to make use of the public data type.

On your code-behind declare your variable as

```
public string name;
//Do whatever assignment operations to your variable "name"
```

And on your aspx page. You can call it

```
<% Response.Write(name); %>
```